# Why do Python 3 show different shape when converting a LIST into a NUMPY ARRAY? Also include the code to convert both lists properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working on an Image Classification Project and after reading the images using CV2, I need to convert the list of images into NumPy array to pass them into model.

Train Data Sample

[image]

Test Data Sample

[image]

As seen in images, the data type for both  TRAIN and TEST is LIST.

Now on converting them to numpy, using

```
X_test1 = np.array(X_test)
X_train1 = np.array(X_train)
```

Resulting Output Shape

[image]

Train Output

[image]

Test Output

[image]

Required Shape:

- X_test - (111,128,128)
- X_train - (332,128,128)

Total - 443 images (111+332) and 128x128 resolution

Comment: Could you post the output for the shape of X_test and X_train. The images show the contents of the lists, and not the exact shapes

Comment: The testing data shape looks fine, but the training data doesn't. please edit the question to include the code that generates both lists.

Comment: @IshwarVenugopal The shapes of X_test and X_train are (111,) and (332,) respectively.